# Adding the Attribute Set name to Google analytics Ga.php?

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I'm trying to add the name of the Attribute Set to my analytics reports in the file */www/app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php*.

This is the code I am using but something isn't right and I keep getting a blank page on the Magento Success page:

```
$attributeSetName = null;

$attributeSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();

foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
     $result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addItem', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
         $order->getIncrementId(),
         $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku()), $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()),
         $attributeSetName,
         $item->getBasePrice(), $item->getQtyOrdered()
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_product` seem to be undefined

Try

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

     $attributeSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();

     $result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addItem', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
         $order->getIncrementId(),
         $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku()), $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()),
         $this->jsQuoteEscape($attributeSetName),
         $item->getBasePrice(), $item->getQtyOrdered()
      );
}
```

Comment: That appears to have worked perfectly. Thanks so much!